# Can Eclipse auto-generate Java comments at the end of a method?

Tags: java, eclipse

More specifically, can it generate a commend that is simply the name of the method? For example, for the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("ping");
}//main  <--This comment, that has the name of the method
```

Comment: What would the purpose of this be? I don't know if it's possible, but I can't see any practical use, so I would assume it isn't.

Comment: @turbo I agree to certain extend. I have heard people referring to it as "Identifying comments" - which people think is helpful in reading long piece of code.

Comment: @turbo It's mostly a "c-ism". Some people like things like `while (x) { code..} // while` and so on (it is somewhat useful for long preprocessor arguments). Not a fan either, but there's precedent for it..

Comment: @turbo, as stated by others, it's simply a personal preference. I think it makes code easier to look through and understand. I also javadoc all my code religiously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to add this to every method ( hand written & generated) you will have to use some code formatting tool like [Jalopy](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/new.html)

There is a nice eclipse plugin for Jalopy by which you can apply your formatting rules on current file or across packages.

See [this incarnation](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/new.html) of Jalopy has exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For generated methods only (will not work on existing ones): Preferences - Java - Templates:

Find the templates for method generation and edit them to your needs (insert comments after the closing bracket using the name-variable).

Example:

```
private ${return_type} ${name}(${}) {
    ${cursor}
}// ${name}
```

Comment: for the method name to appear in a custom comment, use pattern variable `${enclosing_method}`

Comment: This applies to generated methods only.

Comment: @ringbearer Correct, i dont know of any solution that would work on already existing methods.